# Cannot Import anything , I tried using stackoverflow answers but it still did not solve my problem

Tags: python, discord

**Ways i have tried to import stuff**
Use cmd
and use the normal terminal

I am using visual  studio code and im trying to import discord json and pyfiglet

> import discord, json, pyfiglet

Line of code i am trying to use

It says its all sucessfuly installed and if i try to reinstall it just says that the files are already installed

And way to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same python interpreter?

Comment: What went wrong? Was there an error message? This is a problem when trying to execute code in visual studio? How do you do that? Can you open a terminal, run python and import a module such as `import os` (both in visual studio and command line)?

Comment: My issue was that i had mulitple versions of python installed so it did not worked i unistalled other versions and changed my path and that has solved the issue